# Resize extended partition on Linux

Tags: partitioning, debian, gparted

The setup (Raspberry Pi Desktop for PC and Mac - Debian Stretch 9.5 x86_64)

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcff7ff8e

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 312580095 312078338 148.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 312580095 312078336 148.8G 8e Linux LVM
```

**df -h**

```
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                            976M     0  976M   0% /dev
tmpfs                           200M  6.1M  194M   4% /run
/dev/mapper/raspberry--vg-root   23G  4.6G   18G  22% /
tmpfs                           998M     0  998M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                           998M     0  998M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                       236M  101M  123M  46% /boot
/dev/mapper/raspberry--vg-var   9.2G  1.1G  7.6G  13% /var
/dev/mapper/raspberry--vg-home  111G  101G  3.6G  97% /home
/dev/mapper/raspberry--vg-tmp   1.7G  5.3M  1.6G   1% /tmp
tmpfs                           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000
```

**Gparted**

[screenshot-gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acFaq.png)

I installed linux as LVM becouse installer told me that it's best for resizing in future. But installer put LVM inside fixed size extendedpartition which I'm unable to resize. It's mounted so it's understood.

**Gparted Live**

But when I tried to resize from Gparted booted from live-usb this:

[screenshot-gparted-live](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szHuA.png)

Padlock on screen suggest partition is mounted (and cannot be resized) but command line clearly states it's not mounted.

Any ideas how to resize extended partition so I can resize LVM inside it?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is resize the extended partition. It will never be mounted so it should always work.

Comment: I can't resize extended partition. Thats the whole point of my question. I can't do it from within system, nor from system booted from USB. It jus't don't work and I don't know why.

Comment: Ok, so I used different version of live-usb and there was another option avilable (Disable). After disabling LVM I was able to resize extended partition. And after that LVM. Rebooted into Debian and finish the job with lvextend nad resize2fs).

Comment: Gparted should have given more info on what the padlock icon meant, (double-clicking or right-click -> more info IIR). It looks like whatever live USB you were using had automatically mounted the lvm? That's a little disappointing, I don't like it when live USB's go around mounting things on their own, could cause unwanted writes & filesystem changes (apparently even mounting with `ro` could still cause writes :( Not good for last attempts to backup/recover failing drives, or forensics)